# Stream on an incline

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A stream of an ideal liquid flows on an inclined plane. The flow is steady. The depth of the stream decreases by 2 times at distance l. At what distance does the depth of the stream decrease by 4 times?

I have a few doubts in this question:
1)Why does the depth decrease? Is it an application of the equation of continuity?
2)What would happen if the fluid was viscous?

Answer (score 0):

The first part is indeed an application of continuity. Assuming they are refferering to streamilned flow along the incline, it is quite easy to see that: $h_1 . v_1 = h_2.v_2$ where $h_1$and $h_2$ are the depths(w.r.t the incline plane) at 2 different positions, and $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the velocities at those points.

Now for the second part, what if the fluid was viscous?

There will now act a shear stress on the fluid given by

$\tau = \mu. \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, where $\mu$ is the coefficient of viscosity of the fluid, and the partial derivative is the velocity gradient of the liquid perpendicular to its flow.